# The background doesn't round the button tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using tkinter to create a GUI. I use PIL to import an image as the background. Here is my code:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("DFUInfo-v1")
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("background.jpg"))  
l=Label(image=img)
l.pack()
root.configure(bg='white')   

root.geometry("490x280")
```

In my app, buttons are rounded. But when I use the image, the background does not match the round buttons, here is the [image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjGfJ.png)

Can somebody help me pls? Thanks

Comment: ```Label``` doesn't have rounded corners (as far as I know). So even if the Image is rounded, it won't reflect in ```tk.Label```

Comment: so do u know which module can do that

Comment: Which module can round the buttons?

Comment: use a different framework such as PyQt or PyGtk.

Comment: @Art not necessarily, you can create rounded buttons in `Canvas`, also if you use an image with rounded corners and set `relief='flat'` for the button, wouldn't they be kinda rounded?

Comment: @Matiiss OP asked for a library recommendation. Besides, tkinter simply doesn't provide ways to make rounded buttons. You can sure try to make one, but it still wouldn't give you a level of customizability that PyQt offers.  Creating a rounded button in PyQt can be as simple as setting `border-radius: 5px;` in the stylesheet. Using images to make rounded buttons will work only if the size of the button doesn't change.

Comment: @Art using image is one thing but you can create a class with canvas that will do the same thing PyQt can, like setting those borders, and you don't need an image necessarily but at that point I agree that just use PyQt (especially because it is compatible with Android and cross-platform in general as far as I know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can create rounded "buttons" in `tkinter` (what determines the visible shape is how the image looks):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


# use your images here
# open your images (my preference is to use `.open` before initialising `Tk`)
img = Image.open('rounded.png')
# resize to match window geometry
bg = Image.open('space.jpg').resize((500, 400))


# the function to call when button clicked
def func(event=None):
    print('clicked')


root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x400')
# here are the converted images
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bg)

# from now on this will be the "root" window
canvas = Canvas(root, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
# add background
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=bg, anchor='nw')

# create button and you have to use coordinates (probably can make
# custom grid system or sth)
btn = canvas.create_image(250, 200, image=photo, anchor='c')
# bind the "button" to clicking with left mouse button, similarly
# as `command` argument to `Button`
canvas.tag_bind(btn, '<Button-1>', func)

root.mainloop()
```

Most of the explanation is in the code comments, but note that the bound sequence works for the whole image but images are always square so you can click the button being outside of the visible part but only as far as the image goes, it is most certainly possible to create a button that doesn't have such issues but that requires some math

**Important** (suggestion):
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Comment: Seems like the buttons are still not rounded.

Comment: @HuyVuQuang the button's shape/image has to be rounded

Comment: Yes It is. They are always rounded

Comment: @huyvuquang then what is the issue? Btw you can't use `Button` for creating buttons if you want them to be rounded

Comment: So you want me to set a picture for my buttons?

Comment: @HuyVuQuang yes, if you have a picture with rounded edges and transparent bg, you can use that for your button if you place it on canvas, or create a button using canvas methods (`.create_`), if you are still strugling, then please update your question with your current code and a picture of how it looks on GUI, that is if you still have issues, first try doing what I told you just now